We know that $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(m)=-n$ and $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)=-m$. Find the value of $\frac{f(1)+...f(m+n)}{m+n}$.
my question
Let $f: N-> Z, f(x)=ax+b, a,b \in Z$ and $m,n\in N$ and m and n are different numbers. We know that $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(m)=-n$ and $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)=-m$. Find the value of $\frac{f(1)+...f(m+n)}{m+n}$.
my idea
Because $m,n\in N$ and $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(m)=-n$ and $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)=-m$ its clearly that the function f is a decreasing one.
I thought that the equations are simetric and we can suppose WLOG that $n>m$.
This means that $f(1)+...f(m+n)=-n+f(m+1)+...+f(n)$
I don't know what to do forward! Hope one of you can help me!

You have two equations, so you can compute $a$ and $b$.

Define $S$: $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $S(n) = f(1) + f(2) + \dots + f(n)$. Since $f(x) = ax + b$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and constants $a$, $b$, one finds that
$$
S(x) = a(1 + 2 + \dots + x) + bx = a \frac{x(x+1)}{2} + bx.
$$
One knows that
$$
S(m) = a \frac{m(m+1)}{2} + bm = -n
$$
and that
$$
S(n) = a \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + bn = -m
$$
for distinct $m$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
One finds that
$$
S(m+n) = a \frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)}{2} + b(m+n),
$$
so
$$
\frac{S(m+n)}{m+n} = a \frac{m+n+1}{2} + b.
$$
Note that
$$
m-n = S(m) - S(n) = (m-n) \left( a \frac{m+n+1}{2} + b \right).
$$
Since $m - n \neq 0$,
$$
1 = a \frac{m+n+1}{2} + b.
$$
One finally finds that
$$
\frac{S(m+n)}{m+n} = a \frac{m+n+1}{2} + b = 1.
$$

I thank @MartinR for pointing out a silly typo, because of which I gave a wrong answer. I made another silly mistake.
Conclusion: The correct answer is $1$.

The (IMO) interesting fact is that $\frac{S(x+y)}{x+y} = \frac{S(x)-S(y)}{x-y}$ for all distinct $x, y \in \Bbb N$ (which immediately gives the solution). I wonder what the shortest/most elegant proof of that formula would be. – Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1028421/42969

@MartinR I did not know the formula; maybe the person who first recorded this knew.

$$
 S(x) = f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(x) = a \frac{x(x+1)}{2} + bx
$$
is a quadratic polynomial in $x$ with $S(0) = 0$. Every quadratic polynomial without constant term satisfies the functional equation
$$
 (x-y) S(x+y) = (S(x) - S(y)) (x+y)
$$
for all $x, y$. This can be verified easily, e.g. by noting that for fixed $y$ both sides of the equation are cubic polynomials in $x$ with the same leading coefficient, and taking the same value at three points $x= -y, 0, y$. See also Functional Equation: Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x+y)(f(x)-f(y))=(x-y)f(x+y)$ .
It follows that
$$
 \frac{S(m+n)}{m+n} = \frac{S(m)-S(n)}{m-n} = \frac{-n+m}{m-n} = 1 \, .
$$

(Shortest?) The problem statement implies a unique solution. Trying simple values to find it, $m=0,n=1$ leads to $0=1$ so that fails, but $m=1,n=2$ gives:
$$\begin{align}
   & f(1) = -2, \quad   f(1)+f(2) = -1, \quad \text{so}\ \ f(2)=1  \\
  & \Rightarrow a = 3,  \quad   b  = -5 \\
  & \Rightarrow f(1)+f(2)+f(3)=3 \\[5pt]
  & \Rightarrow \frac{f(1)+\dots f(n+m)}{n+m}=\frac33=1
  \end{align} $$

But the solution could depend on $m$ and $n$ ...

Thanks for your answer, because of which I realized that I made a really stupid mistake.

I don't think the solution could depend on $n$ and $m$, because the question "Find the value of ..." should then be answered with "this can not be determined, since it can have different values depending on $n$ and $m$". The way I read the question is that there is a definite answer.
